# how to solve the JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, callback, cordova

hi i am getting the error msgs

when i am calling HTML file i'm using this method

```
url:'http://abcccc/'+data.userId,
success:function(userInfo){
$.cookie('iTouchUser', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
// window.location='list.html';    (i've try this method also)
window.location.replace('file:///android_asset/www/list.html');
```

and the error msgs i am getting is

```
 DroidGap(991): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/list.html)
 DroidGap(991): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/list.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
 PluginManager(991): init()
 CordovaLog(991): JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks.
 CordovaLog(991): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.8.0.js: Line 3708 : JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks.
 Web Console(991): JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.8.0.js:3708
```

I have check it in the  cordova-1.8.0.js:3708 it has

```
// If server is stopping
          else if (xmlhttp.status === 503) {
              console.log("JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks.");
          }
```

any one 've any idea how to solve this error

Comment: Does PhoneGap not work on the list.html page? I suspect the reason you are seeing the "Stopping callbacks" log is that the current callback server is being shutdown so we can start a new one for list.html. In other words I think you are worrying for nothing.

Comment: what i must do for this error any idea

Comment: I want to know cordova and PhoneGap are same?

Comment: Okay, first off I'm not clear as to what your error is. Second, yes PhoneGap and Apache Cordova are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, try using `navigator.app.loadUrl('url')` instead of `window.location`

Comment: still i've a same JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks

Comment: Not sure if it's connected to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-164. Try posting in the PhoneGap Google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap